# Txt document data doesn't format correctly in Excel

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, formatting, copy-paste

Disclaimer - this should be a very simple task, but clearly everything I thought I knew about excel is false.

I'm trying to copy and paste data from a txt document to an excel document. An example of a line I'm trying to copy from the txt doc is: **4512544425701264**.

However, when I paste into excel it pastes as **4512544425701260** but displays in the cell as **4.51254E+15**. This happens for each line of data.

I've tried numerous ways to fix this problem none have worked including:

- Copied the txt data into a Microsoft Word document, then tried
  pasting into the excel.
- Resized the cell.
- Tried each cell formatting option.
- Tried opening the txt doc in Excel, even progressed through the text import wizard. **Interestingly, I noticed the data preview on page 3 displayed the data correctly. But after proceeding past the importer, the data loaded with the same problem.**
- Tried on another PC.
- Copied and pasting one line at a time.

The only solution I have found is manually typing out each line, however this is highly unpractical due to the large amount of data.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To show full number rightclick on cell, choose "Format cells..". In "Number" tab choose "Number" category and set "Decimal places" to zero.

Unfortunately excel lets to put only 15 digits as a number. Every additional number is converted to 0, that is  why your number 451254442570126**4** is converted to 451254442570126**0**

If you don't need this number to be used in calculation, you can format cells to text format before pasting:

[image]

Source on digits limitation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, this is expected behavior (it's Microsoft, after all). I have encountered it frequently when dealing with UPC codes, for example. In order to avoid this, format the cells you are trying to copy this data to as "Text" BEFORE you copy any data over.

Copy your data (CTRL+C), then select the first cell in the range where the data is going, then paste only the values. This should take care of it.

If for some reason you still get scientific notation, provided the cells have the "Text" formatting, you can select that cell, click in the Formula bar and hit ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste into Excel, try calling "Text import wizard" in the Paste Options. This will allow you to set delimiter (in case of CSV) and later data type of a column where you can select **"Text"** which will tell wizard not try to convert your data into numbers.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :(